# How to convert a cmfv file to mp4

Tags: video-conversion, mp4

I have a .cmfv file that I would like to convert into .mp4. I can't seem to find anything about it online.

Is it possible to convert it to .mp4?

Comment: what is a cmfv file?

Comment: @Moab, it is CMAF video.  I think ffmpeg can do this but I am too lazy to research it.

Comment: " but I am too lazy to research it." That is one of the requirements here at SU before asking a question.

Comment: I don't understand @Moab.. I thought that I get to pick and choose what I answer and what I research.  Today I am just not feeling it but I thought that I could give you the answer to the question you asked.  I meant no offense and I like helping out here.

Comment: You are expected to do some research before asking a question.

Comment: @Moab calm yourself, please, then look at the name of the person who asked the question, and then the name of the person you're getting all riled up towards. Note the important fact that the names are NOT the same. Now, proceed.

Comment: OP, you really should do some web searching first. While you note that you "can't seem to find anything about it online", doing a search for the file type returns a LOT of information, much of it very helpful-looking, such as explanations about what that file type represents (an encapsulated .mp4 file, one of the first results suggests), which should give you a few more clues about what you ought to do regarding that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the .cmfv file to end with .mp4 extension. That trick worked with VLC in Windows, at least, with a file I had around.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.